# Tabulator editor: "select" scrolls left on select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

I have vue tabulator control with the following options.

```html
<vue-tabulator v-model="locations" class="locations" :options="tabulartorLocationOptions"></vue-tabulator>
```

```js
tabulartorLocationOptions:{
    columns: [
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
        { title: 'Roof Year Built', field: 'roofYearBuilt' , editor:"select", editorParams:constructionCodes},
    ]                
},
```

And the following data

```js
locations:[{roofYearBuilt: 2007}],
```

Whenever I select an option the entire table scrolls to the left. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You appear to have declared the same column many times? each column must have a unique `field` value. Also without seeing your table in action it is hard to offer advice on the scroll, i would suggest you link to a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue

Comment: The multiple columns are just to get the scroll to appear. Tabulator is fine with duplicate columns. same issue happens with unique columns. It seems to be an issue with vue tabulator and not tabulator itself.

Comment: I wrote tabulator, it is not fine with columns of the same field. If you try and do anything that references the field names like sorting or getting cells by column field it will not behave correctly

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment it is not possible to see from your posted code what the issue is. You will need to post a link to a fiddle to demonstrate the issue

Comment: cool will post a js fidddle soon.